# How much safety logic should I include in my private components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After building out quite a few React components, adding propTypes, writing tests, and adding occasional default props, I'm still left questioning how much safety is too much. After dabbling with Flow types, I'm starting to get the feeling that I need to add more safety checks that all of the expected data is present before attempting to render content.

One benefit of extra safety I could see is ensuring that components always properly render, even when APIs fail. On the other hand, APIs failing might be better handled by failing fast. These components are very internal and their uses are pretty explicit and easy to track down.

Current component:

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.items.slice(4)
      .map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>);
  }
}
```

With safety:

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.items &&
      this.props.items.length &&
      this.props.items.length > 3 &&
      this.props.items.slice(4)
        .map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>);
  }
}
```

Is this over engineering?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If a component will accept user input, that input should be validated. Failures caused by improper use of the component, should fail fast so that they can be corrected in development and never hit a production environment.